# Minecraft servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing an offline server then my pc ran out of battery then when I opened minecraft again the server was deleted. Can I get the server back? My pc isn't that good so that might be the problem.

Comment: Collop, Did the world completely disappear (like it's not in your single-player list anymore) or is it still there, but just unsaved of any changes?

Answer (score 1):

Well if its a single player world then no the game was erased from your computer because u didn't save it before your computer died so it gone foever!

if it was a multiplayer that u somewhat made offline then yes but thats 99% not the case

Answer (score -1):

Well, I understood in your brief description that your servers that would have been in the 'Multiplayer' tab, have disappeared. This is a glitch in minecraft that I have encountered on various times. There is currently no way to fix this to my knowledge.